# Render complex json and filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

Trying to implement a select box with filtering I've got some performance problems (initial loading time is not acceptable - especially in IE) rendering a heavy complex (about 30 categories, each category contains about 30 subjects, each subject holds up to 10 topics) json using KnockoutJS.

```
[
   {
      "id":0,
      "name":"Category #1",
      "subjects":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Subject #1",
            "topics":[
               {
                  "name":"Topic #1"
               },
               ...
            ]
         },
         ...
      ]
   },
   ...
]
```

Tried using nested foreach bingings:

```
<ul class="categories" data-bind="foreach: data">
        <li class="category">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <ul data-bind="foreach: subjects">
                <li class="subject">
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: topics">
                        <li class="topic">
                            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Can you suggest how to make it work properly? Maybe there are some plugins which do this?

Comment: 9000 items is an awful  lot to render. Streamline to render as needed based on user interactions

Comment: can you provide any examples of that?

Comment: Don't know if you're able to edit your data source, but with large amounts of data like this, you should do the filtering in the back-end where the data comes from so you don't send lots of data in the response. This will drastically decrease the loading time. Send your filters (maybe add pagination?) with the ajax call and do the filtering before you send the requested data back.

Comment: It's hard to help optimize without the data set, but I would highly recommend using Chrome's Performance monitor to see what is driving up the load times. You may benefit from a [rate limited extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html), or hiding depth in the dom with the `if` binding.

Comment: thank you all for the help, decided to go with https://github.com/thinkloop/knockout-js-progressive-filter